# IFTTT always show "Please fill out all Applet defaults for the trigger"

Tags: ifttt

I am working on IFTTT development,the service checklist always show "Please fill out all Applet defaults for the trigger".
But I am sure that I fill out all Applet defaults correctly.
If I delete the trigger , service checklist will pass.
So the problem is the trigger.
What is the problem?

I attach some pictures.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9XZ3.png)
[trigger info screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHUQG.png)

Comment: This is a question regarding a paid IFTTT service and not programming. There's probably an IFTTT support forum or email contact that would be better.

Comment: @EricCochran I just got a reply from ifttt, this bug has been repaired, thank you for your help.